# Differences Between PyroCMS and CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

I am trying to learn how to make a site with PyroCMS. I know it is similar to CodeIgniter, but I have not worked on either in the past. I was wondering if anyone could tell me the differences, as most sites talking about PyroCMS will inevitably mention CodeIgniter as an explanation for anything potentially confusing about PyroCMS, but as they are tutorials about Pyro, they will not explain how to program in CodeIgniter. What is frustrating about this is they will not go into many core differences between the two, either, so it's not as easy as looking up a CodeIgniter tutorial and changing a few things.

I was wondering if anyone could tell me the main differences to watch out for that would be relevant for these tutorials. For example, the folder structure seems to be similar, but CodeIgniter has an Applications folder, while Pyro probably has another folder that does the same thing, but the Pyro tutorials don't say what that similar folder is.

Comment: It looks like PyroCMS is built on top of CodeIgniter.

Comment: PyroCMS is a CMS and codeigniter is MVC framework PyroCMS  built on codeigniter

Comment: I think so, but that means the CodeIgniter doesn't show, all you really see is the Pyro.

Comment: You are asking What is the difference between paint and painting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PyroCMS](https://www.pyrocms.com/) is a CMS build on CodeIgniter. PyroCMS is used by individuals, small & medium-sized businesses, and large organizations worldwide to easily create & build a variety of websites & web-enabled applications.

[CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) is an Application Development Framework - a toolkit - for people who build web sites using PHP. Its goal is to enable you to develop projects much faster than you could if you were writing code from scratch, by providing a rich set of libraries for commonly needed tasks, as well as a simple interface and logical structure to access these libraries. CodeIgniter lets you creatively focus on your project by minimizing the amount of code needed for a given task.

**UPDATE:**
One good overview for PyroCMS you can read [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/whats-pyrocms/)

Comment: I know pretty much what CodeIgniter and Pyro are. I was asking about the differences in how one codes in them.

Comment: @trysis  update a answer and post one good overview for PyroCMS

Comment: I have read a lot of the overviews and tutorials, etc., but as I said in the question, none (or not many) of them say the differences between PyroCMS and CodeIgniter, yet still mention CodeIgniter as an explanation for anything confusing about Pyro. I am trying to learn PyroCMS without already knowing CodeIgniter.

Comment: I would advice you to learn some concepts of CodeIgniter and it will help you to learn more easy the PyroCMS, because they have a almost the same construct.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do that, as well. The site I am creating right now has to be in Pyro, but I am trying to learn all I can about both, as I will probably use both in the future.

Comment: I work on CI more than two years and I really love CI framework. I am sure that you will like it when you will start to adapt on it.

Comment: Oh, I am not saying I will not like it. My entire company uses it for most of its sites, so I suppose I will either love it or learn to live with it.

Answer (score 0):

PyroCMS is built using modular MVC, which means (in short) that each part of the system is its own micro-instance of MVC. This allows the system to be more flexible and cleanly organized than other CMS platforms. PyroCMS describes itself as a simple, flexible, community driven content management system.” And because PyroCMS is powered by CodeIgniter (at least for a bit longer, while the team migrates over to a Laravel backend), it is easy to learn, understand, and own.

CodeIgniter (CI) is one of popular php framework,it is very help full whenever we need to build large websites using php.It has so many libraries,helpers and plugins.But, CodeIgniter is not everything. We will not find 'engine generator' that can build page self. Several frameworks have features like that. For example, they can create web page (that to do basic Create, Read, Update, and Delete operation) automatically. CodeIgniter doesn't do this.

But codeigniter is very useful to decrease our code maximally without loosing functionalists.